# Is it possible to Send emails from a Google Sheet Script without Authorization?

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I have a Google Sheet that we use at work for New and Departing users from the org for our team. 
Our team lead will just fill in the information and then check a box that says notify team. We will get an email with a summary of the information our team lead added. We then go to the Google Sheet and check off boxes of what has been done for that new or departed user so the whole team knows what things have been done.

Problem I am facing is that every so often the Google Sheet looses authentication from me to send out emails.

So two questions come out of this:

1. What happens if I ever leave the org how would emails send out?
2. Is there not a way to use some other way to approve this Google Sheet to send out emails to our team without the need for a users account to do it?

Info: I am currently using the [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) Class to send out emails

Comment: I have several sheets running for a long time and don't recall ever having a script 'loose authentication' unless someone else was editing the script I can't think of why it would. 2. Create a service account, transfer ownership of the sheet to that account and auth the script from there.

Comment: The sheet is in a shared drive the company owns it not a user. I'm not sure why but every so often I get an email with script error it can't send email. We change passwords every 90 days and have 2FA I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it on Gsuite

Comment: Does the email need to go out from your account or could it simply go out from the account of whoever is editing it?

Comment: @SteveMain then it's best to have that company account running the script and sending the email. You could include the name / email of the user that triggered the email in the email its self. There is a big difference between the script losing authorisation and receiving a runtime error email. If a script isn't authorised it won't run in the first place and no error email will be sent. I'm 99% sure that the password change and 2FA have no impact on the auth of a script since I've changed my password several times and haven't had to re-auth scripts. What is the error you get in the email?

Comment: @SourabhChoraria No I would prefer it to come from a different account as I send the email to a distribution group that I am in and because I sent it i don't get a copy of the email. SO maybe a service account might work best.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it possible to send emails from Google Sheet Script without
  authorization?

Not really, to send emails you need at least to be authenticated on gmail and at the same time you need to have access to the email addresses you are trying to send mails to.

- What happens if I ever leave the org how would emails send out?

If you are loosing authentication from time to time, as you are saying, it won't eventually work. Also, if your user gets deleted it won't work also.

- Is there not a way to use some other way to approve this Google Sheet
  to send out emails to our team without the need for a users account
  to do it?

Well, service accounts are exactly though for this, a service account is a special type of account that represent non-human user that needs to be authenticate and authorized to access data in Google APIs, often on behalf of other users.

**Here you have some documentation:**

[Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)

[Using service accounts](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/blocks/using-service-accounts)

[Using service account on Apps Script - OAuth Library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#using-service-accounts)

But certainly this process is more complicated and may be an overkill for what you really need here...

A simpler option is to use a standard user account just for this matter, to send this emails, lets call it: no-reply@mydomain.com

For the sake of security the Admin can limit what this account has access to on the Admin Console, and that would solve your problems without creating new ones or adding more complexity to your tasks, later on you could always move to a service account and impersonate that user.

---

**About the re-login problems:**

Yes, they are due to this security measure of 90 days pass expiration.

As far as you do not change the pass or manually close the session for the user running the script it should not require new authentication process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wish there way a way to from the Admin console approve this Google Sheet to use this Class unrestricted. Looks like I might have to use a service account to send out email.